# Peaks possibility with structure factor for BCC and FCC

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, interference, diffraction, x-ray-crystallography

I have a doubt regarding what peaks are possible for BCC and FCC atoms. Say $n_{1}$, $n_{2}$ and $n_{3}$ are coordinates which are only integers such that for atom A, $n_{1}+n_{2}+n_{3}$ is odd and for atom B, the sum $n_{1}+n_{2}+n_{3}$ is even, they cant we say that both atoms at maximal conclusion both being FCC.

Note- I know that for peaks to be possible in BCC, sum of the 3 entries must be even and for FCC, each individual 3 entries either be even or odd.

But don't we think that most probably the answer should be both atoms being FCC, as BCC fails for atom A condition that sum being odd we get no peak so most probably is that it should be FCC, but there are cases where FCC for atom A fails too with mixed entries, like (347),  although sum odd given no peak but there are cases for FCC s.t., sum is odd we do get peak. Same is the case for FCC that, sum being even we get peaks but for some cases again like (321), we don't get peaks but BCC will definitely give peaks.

Comment: Are A and B in the same crystal?

Comment: No they are two different systems

Comment: What do you mean by atoms A and B? The three numbers are Miller indices - which refer to planes and not individual atoms. Do you mean peaks A and B?